# How to fire trigger with azure scheduler?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have created scheduler with azure automation now I want to fire trigger to particular schedule wise. I have searched a lot but in this I have found trigger every N minute. but it's not related to scheduler.

Can I fire trigger schedule wise ??
for example, I have created one schedule to schedule every 5 minutes. so I want to callback function for every 5 minutes.

Is it possible with azure ??

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to accomplish, because it is not clear? You want to run your runbook every hour or what?

Comment: @OlehTarasenko Hii, I have created many events in calandar for particulat time so I want to send push notification each events to mobile side. so I have to generate scheduler event wise and want to call back that function within particular time so I can add notification in queue.

Comment: @OlehTarasenko simply schedule a notification

Comment: You need to attach your scheduler to runbook (peace of code for sending notification in your case, the logic of your app, module, etc.)

Comment: @OlehTarasenko means I have to write my all logic into  PowerShell rubook page inside azure portal

Answer (score 0):

That should be enough, did you add the schedule to your runbook?

Comment: yes, I have created scheduler from code side and now how can identify that call back of that particular scheduler?

Comment: Runbook can callback my function or url ?

Comment: Yes, it can, but you need to write this logic in the runbook. Please take a look as an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-powershell

Comment: @OlehTarasenko let me check